# Cause of cx_Freeze "internal objdump command failed" error in OSX Sierra?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build a project using cx_Freeze.

The project builds, but crashes whenever I open it.

During the build I'm getting this error...

fatal error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed
```

I have updated Xcode.

I have tried building a project with no dependencies.

The problem doesn't seem to be any dependencies or the code.

As near as I can tell it's something to do with xcode???

Does anyone know the fix?

Below is thecommand line used to build:

```
22:cx_freeze_build_test 22$ python3.5 setup.py bdist_mac
running bdist_mac
running build
running build_exe
creating directory build/exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.5
copying /Users/t22/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/cx_Freeze/bases/Console -> build/exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.5/main
copying /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python -> build/exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.5/Python
writing zip file build/exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.5/lib/python35.zip
```

The error part of the build...

```
3.5/urllib/parse.pyc': The file was not recognized as a valid object file.
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: input file: build/Testing cx_Freeze build-1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/xml/__init__.pyc is not a Mach-O file
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump: 'build/Testing cx_Freeze build-1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/xml/__init__.pyc': The file was not recognized as a valid object file.
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: input file: build/Testing cx_Freeze build-1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/xml/parsers/__init__.pyc is not a Mach-O file
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump: 'build/Testing cx_Freeze build-1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/xml/parsers/__init__.pyc': The file was not recognized as a valid object file.
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: input file: build/Testing cx_Freeze build-1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/xml/parsers/expat.pyc is not a Mach-O file
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump: 'build/Testing cx_Freeze build-1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/xml/parsers/expat.pyc': The file was not recognized as a valid object file.
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed
prepare_qt_app()
22:cx_freeze_build_test 22$
```

Comment: Xcode is version Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Comment: did you find the way to solve this? If you pls share. Now, I'm getting same error.